# How to create an account in dynamics 365 with custom attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I can create account with custom attributes. I have one attribute which is type of list. I can't understand how to add it. Code sample:

```
retrievedAccount["custom_attribute"] = new OptionSetValue((int)MyEnum.FirstValue);
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by "a type of list"? Is that a multi-select choice?